# C++ Can constant class data be optimized out of class by compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, memory-layout, object-layout

I know that constant variables outside classes can be optimized directly into function calls by the compiler, but is it legal for the compiler to do the same for constant class variables?

If there is a class declared like this:

```
class A {
public:
const int constVar;
    //other, modifiable variables

A(int val): constVar(val) {
         //code to initialize modifiable variables

}
};
```

and I create an instance of A and call a function like this:

```
A obj(-2);
int absoluteVal = std::abs(A.constVar);
```

is the compiler allowed to do this instead and make the class be `sizeof(int)` smaller?:

```
A obj();
int absoluteVal = std::abs(-2);
```

Comment: You can check what your compiler does with various flags at https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Don't think the optimzer is allowed to change the `sizeof(A)`.

Comment: @RickAstley Perhaps not, but it may inline `const` class members. You can inline without eliminating the original function or object.

Comment: Do not mix `compile-time constant` with `constant`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the "as-if" rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule)

Comment: and the answer is yes; I've seen entire classes be optimised away with trivial examples, and presumably this can become distinctly non-trivial as the optimisation level rises and things like LTO are factored in. You should be able to test this for yourself using simple examples, as I did.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are interested in the general rule of whether optimizer could remove a const from the memory layout of a class (which could be more complex than your simplified example) and not in specific code generation related to your simplified example ?

Comment: @Christophe I tried to convey that with the comments inside the class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler is free to emit any code that preserves the "observable behavior" of the program (there is an exception with copy constructor which can be elided even if it has observable behavior, but it doesn't apply here). This is called the [as if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)

```
struct X { int x; };

auto foo()
{
  X x{24};

  return x.x;
}
```

any decent compiler will optimize the above to this:

```
foo():                                # @foo()
        mov     eax, 24
        ret
```

As you can see, it doesn't have anything to do with constness (well, almost), just with observable behavior. You can try and play with the code adding in complexity and see how smart is the compiler in figuring out it can remove the code related to the class instance. Hint: it is very smart.

---

Is not clear to me what you mean by this:

> is the compiler allowed to do this instead and make the class be
>   sizeof(int) smaller?:

I can tell you that: for a type `X` and an object `x` of such type `sizeof(x)` is always `= sizeof(X)` regardless of instantiations of the class. In other words the size of the class is determined when the class is defined, and as such it is not influenced by possible instantiations or lack of. The size of a class is the sum of all the sizes of its non-static data members plus padding. The padding is implementation defined and can be usually be somewhat controlled (e.g. packed structs). So no, the size of a class can never be smaller than the sum of the sizes all it's non-static non-reference data members.

Comment: Constness still has *something* to do with it. The optimizer has to prove that removing code won't have observable behaviour. And it is often much easier to prove that a const object won't change value, than non-const. In this example, the proof is quite easy without constness of course.

Comment: @user2079303 I think you'll find this interesting: [Understanding Compiler Optimization - Chandler Carruth - Opening Keynote Meeting C++ 2015](https://youtu.be/FnGCDLhaxKU) - and I think you'll find that he disagrees with you; `const` is basically *useless* to the optimizer.

Comment: While you are completely right on everything you say, you don't really answer the general question of whether the compiler is allowed to shorten the object.  Ok, here, constant propagation + dead code elimination + absence of other observable behavior allows the instantiation to be optimized away.  But what if the object would really be used somewhere (e.g. if the object would be written to a file).  FOr example here https://godbolt.org/g/FZ1WiV you see that the object is instantiated and the constant initialized despite being optimized away in the computation.

Answer (score 2):

It would be perfectly legal for the compiler to generate

```
int absoluteVal = 2;
```

If `abs` has no side effects. It all hinges on "observable behaviour" (the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)). If you *cannot tell* from the outside that the compiler made some transformation, then it is legal for the compiler to make that transformation.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  But OP asks also if the compiler would be allowed to make the object shorter

Comment: @Christophe making the object smaller would be pretty obviously observable. So, as far as I know, the answer would be no.

Answer (score 2):

#### Code optimizing and object memory layout don't obey the same rules

The C++ standard states the following about the **memory layout of the objects**:

> **1.8/2:** Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject, a base class subobject, or an
>   array element. (...)
>
> **9.2/13:** Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control are **allocated** so that later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static
>   data members with different access control is unspecified.
>   Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members
>   not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might
>   requirements for space for managing virtual functions and virtual base
>   classes.

This guarantees that non static const members (which are data members, even if they are const) are contained within the object.  So the compiler is not allowed to shorten the size of an object.

However, the compiler is authorized to perform **code optimization** such as constant propagation and dead code elimination, reordering, etc. as long as the observable behavior is not altered:

> **1.9/5:** A conforming implementation executing a well-formed program shall produce the same observable behavior as one of the possible
>   executions of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with
>   the same program and the same input. (...)

So if your const member is not `volatile` nor `atomic<>`, the compiler can very well generate

```
A obj();              // size not touched.  And const member will be initialized if needed
int absoluteVal = 2;  // constant propagation + inlining (the object is not even accessed)
```

#### Additional information

Here an example where the object can't be optimized away :

```
A obj(-2);                                 // object is constructed
int absoluteVal = std::abs(obj.constVar);  // will be optimized a way into = 2 
std::cout<<absoluteVal<<std::endl;
size_t lo = sizeof(obj);
std::cout<<lo<<std::endl; 
std::cout.write((char*)&obj, lo);         // obj is written to a stream 
                                          // and output of content at &obj adress is observable behavior
```

You can [see online on the optimizer results](https://godbolt.org/g/nX4h9V) : despite the computation of `absoluteVal` being optimized away, the object is instantiated in its full length **and its constant is initialized**:

```
    ...
    mov     esi, 2                      ; this is absoluteVal calculation
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], -2      ; the const in [rsp+12] object is nevertheless initialized
    ...
    lea     rsi, [rsp+12]               ; the address of the object 
    mov     edx, 4                      ; and its length 
    ...                                 ; are used to call cout.write()
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::write(char const*, long)
```

This is because the observable behavior of writing this trivially copyable object to a stream requires every byte of the object to fit to the expectations.

Comment: Shorten the size, no, but it can get rid of `obj` altogether... as bolov showed, the instantiation of the class can be elided completely if it is not used for anything (i.e. anything else, after constant propagation)

Comment: @underscore_d yes, but this is a different thing : the elision of the instantiation is result of dead code elimination after constant propagation.  This works in this specific example, because the object is not used for any other purpose.  But the instantiation would not be eliminated if the address of the object would be used in an `std::ostream::write()` because the object would be needed to ensure the observable behavior.  It would not be eliminated either it the constructor would do some observable behaviors such as side effects instead of just initializing the const.