# Is it a missed optimization, when a compile-time known reference takes space in a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, reference, initialization, language-lawyer

See this example:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int &b = a;
};
```

Is it a missed optimization, if `sizeof(Foo)!=sizeof(int)`?

I mean, can the compiler remove `b` from the struct, as it always refers to `a`?

Is there anything which stops the compiler to make this transformation?

(Note, `struct Foo` looks as it is. No constructors, etc. But you can add anything around `Foo`, which shows that this optimization would violate the standard)

Comment: Follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811424/is-it-a-missed-optimization-when-a-compile-time-known-reference-takes-space-in

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, because you can use aggregate initialization of a variable to have it refer to something else.

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int &b = a;
};

int c;
Foo f{7, c};
```